# How do I get a specific key in the firebase databse and compare them if they are the same?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been making a project using firebase for a delivery system app.
[image: Firebase Database]

**Problem:** In this image, I need to get these two keys(or parent I think) and store them in a string or if possible I just want to know if I can check if the Id in user has a duplicate. How to check if these key has duplicate or exist and store it on a string if it does exist.

Updated code,

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manageordergrocery);

    mRecyclerView2= findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
    mRecyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mModel2 = new ArrayList<>();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mAdapter2=new ViewHolder1(Manageordergrocery.this, mModel2);
    mRecyclerView2.setAdapter(mAdapter2);
    mDatabaseReference2= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    mDatabaseReference2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                String myParentNode = postSnapshot.getKey();
                mDatabaseReference2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                mDatabaseReference2.orderByKey().equalTo(myParentNode).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String saveNode = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                        mDatabaseReference2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(saveNode).child("Ordered");
                        mDatabaseReference2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    Model1 model2 = postSnapshot.getValue(Model1.class);
                                    mModel2.add(model2);
                                }
                                mAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(Manageordergrocery.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


}
```

Can someone help me, please? I'm still new in firebase and don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain the two keys you can do the following:

```
mDatabaseReference2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
mDatabaseReference2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            String myParentNode = postSnapshot.getKey();
            mDatabaseReference  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            mDatabaseReference.orderByKey().equalTo(myParentNode).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              for(DataSnapshot posts :dataSnapshot.getChildren())
               {
                    String key = posts.getKey();
                    if(key.equals(myParentNode))
                          Toast.makeText(Manageordergrocery.this,"equals", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               } 
              }

           @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
         });
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(Manageordergrocery.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Here first you add a reference to node `User` then you loop inside that node and retrieve the `key` using `getKey()`. After that you attach another listener to the root location and using `orderByKey().equalTo(myParentNode)` you can check if you have two keys with the same value and do the required.

Comment: How do I check if the two keys are the same?

Comment: as I explained, first you retrieve the key that is under the `user` node then using `orderByKey().equalTo(myParentNode)` it will check if there is another key with same value

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much. Last question if it found another key can I use String savekey = datasnapshot.getKey(); to save that duplicated one I mean like I would like to save the uid after it checks if it has duplication.

Comment: yes you can do that, but it is better if you change your database right now in the second listener you are going to be looping inside the whole database since you added the `uid` under the root node, so its preferable to change the database to something else...

Comment: Hmmm yeah someone told me my structure is not right can you help me like fix it or better teach me how to create a good structure?

Comment: check this article https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you check my code? I have updated it above, the app crashes and the error is  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: probably better to ask it in another question and do not add screenshot of code, instead of copy the code and add it as a snippet to your question